# Replace color strings in HTML string within tags

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, replace, regex-group

I have a string that contains HTML. Now I want to replace all occurrences of colors within tags with something. How do I do this?

```js
const workInProgressRegex = /<[\w]+[^>]*>.*?(#(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{3}){1,2})<\/[\w]+>/gim;

const exampleString1 = `<div><span class="foo" style="background-color: #ffffff;">#222222 foo #111111 abc #000000</span></div>`;

const exampleString2 = `<div><span class="foo" style="background-color: #ffffff;">"'#222222 foo #111111 abc #000000</span></div>`;

const result1 = exampleString1.replaceAll(workInProgressRegex, "bar");
// should be `<div><span class="foo" style="background-color: #ffffff;">bar foo bar abc bar</span></div>`

const result2 = exampleString1.replaceAll(workInProgressRegex, "bar");
// should be `<div><span class="foo" style="background-color: #ffffff;">"'bar foo bar abc bar</span></div>`
```

***Additional info:*** I want to replace all text occurrences of any hex colors inside the HTML tags. The examples I gave are just examples and not exhaustive.

Although I am not looking for something unbreakable, it should be robust. That means, the hex codes can be at any position inside the innerHTML, they do not have to be at the end or beginning. There also can be an arbitrary amount of those hex codes in the tag.

Comment: [Parsing HTML with regex is a hard job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/372239)
HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.

Comment: @Toto Yeah, it seems like it. I wanted a "simpler" / "easier" solution (which I define by the number of lines :D). But I guess I'll go for parsing that string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this regex `(#[0-9|a-f]{6})` which should select all of your hex color codes.

https://regex101.com/r/Xvct56/2/

Comment: No, that regex includes `#ffffff` (from the style attribute). Which I don't want to replace.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't simply replace all occurences of #xxxxxx because that would also remove `style="background-color: #ffffff;"` from your string which is what you want to keep.

What you can do however is chaining two replace functions where the first one looks for the pattern **#xxxxxx[empty space]** and the second one for **#xxxxxx<** (because of the last occurence `#000000</span>` which would be replaced by `bar /span>` otherwise).

```js
const exampleString2 = `<div><span class="foo" style="background-color: #ffffff;">"'#222222 foo #111111 abc #000000</span></div>`;

var res = exampleString2.replace(new RegExp(/(#[0-9|a-f]{6} )/, 'g'), 'bar ').replace(new RegExp(/(#[0-9|a-f]{6}<)/, 'g'), 'bar<');
console.log(res);
```